# Does daskarray.map_overlap(array, func) supports multiple arguments?

Tags: python, dask-distributed

`Dask.map_overlap(x, func)`, func only takes a `DaskArray` as a solo input parameter, can I pass extra parameters?
I created a sudo func to take only `daskarray` as input parameter, and inside func(array) I called real function with daskarray and other parameters. But I got a client serialization error.

I am using DASK to do seismic data computation using HPC nodes. I have a `funcA` created by cpython, which takes dask array and other 3 parameters. I use `da.map_overlap` to call that `funcA`, if I long pass dask array parameter, it works fine. But if I pass extra parameters, I got client serialization error.

First I define a function in `abc.pyx`

```
#Cython code to compute abc

cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

DTYPE = np.float32
ctypedef np.float32_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)  # turn off negative index wrapping for entire function

cpdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] abc(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] f, int x, int y, int z):
    cdef int nx=f.shape[0], ny = f.shape[1], nz = f.shape[2]
    cdef int wx=1, wy=1, wz=4

    wx = x
    wy = y
    wz = z

    output  = np.zeros([nx, ny, nz], dtype=DTYPE)
    return output
```

I use `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` to get the `abc.so` file and copy `abc.so` to the `site_packages` directory.

I have `compute_abc.py`:

```
import dask.array as da
from abc import abc
from dask.distributed import wait
import os

class compute_abc(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # super.__init__()
        self.validated = False
        self.win_x = 1
        self.win_y = 1
        self.win_z = 4
        pass

    def set_params(self, client, in_file, out_file, parameters=None):
        self.client = client
        self.in_file = in_file
        self.output_path = out_file
        self.validated = True
        if parameters is not None:
            if "win_x" in parameters:
                self.win_x = int(parameters["win_x"])
            if "win_y" in parameters:
                self.win_y = int(parameters["win_y"])
            if "win_z" in parameters:
                self.win_z = int(parameters["win_z"])

    def run(self):
        if not self.validated:
            print("Can't run, parameters were not validated")
            return

        if not isinstance(self.in_file, da.core.Array):
            chunkdata = da.from_zarr(self.in_file)
            chunkdata = self.client.persist(chunkdata)
        else:
            chunkdata = self.in_file

        def func(data):
            return abc(data, self.win_x, self.win_y, self.win_z)

        depth = {0: self.win_x, 1: self.win_y, 2: self.win_z}
        boundary = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}
        daskout = da.map_overlap(chunkdata, abc, depth=depth, boundary=boundary, trim=True, dtype=chunkdata.dtype)
        daskout = self.client.persist(daskout)

        tmppath = os.path.dirname(self.output_path)
        if os.path.isdir(tmppath):
            daskout.to_zarr(self.output_path)
        else:
            print('Invalid path')

        return chunkdata, daskout
```

I have a test class to call `compute_abc`:

```
import sys
from . import compute_abc
from dask.distributed import Client
import ast

def main(argv):
    param = ast.literal_eval('{"win_x": 1, "win_y": 1, "win_z": 4}')
    comp_abc = compute_abc()
    client = Client()
    comp_abc.set_params(client, '../data_zarr/seismic/seismic.zarr', '../dataOut/seismic/seismic_semblance.zarr', param)
    data_in, res_abc = compute_abc.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I expected the `daskout` to contain the daskarray as result of computation. But I got client serialization error as following:

```
daskout.to_zarr(self.output_path)
  File "/glb/data/cdis_projects/users/ussnis/miniconda3/envs/pvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 2228, in to_zarr
    return to_zarr(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/glb/data/cdis_projects/users/ussnis/miniconda3/envs/pvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 2808, in to_zarr
    **kwargs
  File "/glb/data/cdis_projects/users/ussnis/miniconda3/envs/pvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zarr/creation.py", line 120, in create
    chunk_store=chunk_store, filters=filters, object_codec=object_codec)
  File "/glb/data/cdis_projects/users/ussnis/miniconda3/envs/pvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zarr/storage.py", line 323, in init_array
    object_codec=object_codec)
  File "/glb/data/cdis_projects/users/ussnis/miniconda3/envs/pvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zarr/storage.py", line 337, in _init_array_metadata
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/glb/data/cdis_projects/users/ussnis/miniconda3/envs/pvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 46, in dumps
    for key, value in data.items()
  File "/glb/data/cdis_projects/users/ussnis/miniconda3/envs/pvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 47, in <dictcomp>
    if type(value) is Serialize
  File "/glb/data/cdis_projects/users/ussnis/miniconda3/envs/pvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 164, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', '(subgraph_callable, (subgraph_callable, (<built-in function getitem>, (<function concatenate3 at 0x2b7d1278f400>, (<function concrete at 0x2b7d119f62f0>, [[["(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 2.1, 1.1, 0.09999999999999998)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 2.1, 1.1, 1)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 2.1, 1.1, 1.9)"], ["(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 2.1, 2, 0.09999999999999998)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 2.1, 2, 1)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 2.1, 2, 1.9)"], ["(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 2.1, 2.9, 0.09999999999999998)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 2.1, 2.9, 1)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 2.1, 2.9, 1.9)"]], [["(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3, 1.1, 0.09999999999999998)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3, 1.1, 1)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3, 1.1, 1.9)"], ["(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3, 2, 0.09999999999999998)", "(\'from-zarr-1b4273213cbfa6c35d3560d23e8e8c89\', 2, 1, 0)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3, 2, 1.9)"], ["(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3, 2.9, 0.09999999999999998)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3, 2.9, 1)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3, 2.9, 1.9)"]], [["(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3.9, 1.1, 0.09999999999999998)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3.9, 1.1, 1)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3.9, 1.1, 1.9)"], ["(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3.9, 2, 0.09999999999999998)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3.9, 2, 1)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3.9, 2, 1.9)"], ["(\'concatenate-getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3.9, 2.9, 0.09999999999999998)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3.9, 2.9, 1)", "(\'getitem-33b7b6bef20ae67990d1e0e68e6462ff\', 3.9, 2.9, 1.9)"]]])), (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None))), "(\'from-zarr-1b4273213cbfa6c35d3560d23e8e8c89\', 2, 1, 0)"), "(\'from-zarr-1b4273213cbfa6c35d3560d23e8e8c89\', 2, 1, 0)")')
    err_contains_array(path)
```

If I make the abc function only take data as input parameter and hard coded x, y, z inside abc function, it works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please edit your original question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the issue you are having. It is hard to understand the problem if you do not post a working example of the code, *and* the **specific** error you are seeing.

Comment: I edited the question adding more code in there. Hopefully it helps to solve this problem.

Comment: Basically the problem is map_overlap does not support multiple parameter for the function. map_blocks can. I can do da.map_blocks(abc, array, x, y, z). But I can only do  da.map_overlap(array, abc). If I create a sudo function to wrap abc(x, y, z), I got client serialization failure.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the way to add parameters for the function when calling da.map_overlap(). da.map_overlap(array, func, depth, boundary, trim, param1=value, param2=value,...)